# ld: library not found for -lAPDAdColonyAdapter

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9, appodeal

I am currently using Appodeal framework to monetize my iOS app.I have installed Appodeal framework using CocoaPods without any errors.But when I'm trying to build my application I get such error:

```
ld: library not found for -lAPDAdColonyAdapter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a lot of things.I added $(inherited) to flags and that did not help, but adding $(inherited) to Library Search Paths really helped!